# the incr plugin of oh-my zsh cannot handle spaces correctly when auto-completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, oh-my-zsh

[Operation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjAdK.gif)

As show in the picture, I want to input clea, not clear. But the auto-completion put clear in the screen, when I input `blank` after `a`, the `r` character in still on the screen, which is very bothering.

The incr plugin is [here](https://mimosa-pudica.net/zsh-incremental.html), it's a bash file, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: _it's a bash file_  : What makes you think so? Fortunately it isn't. If it were, it likely would not work with zsh. BTW, your question seems to be more suitable for [so], because it is not really about programming.

Comment: @user1934428 This. Is. Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I wanted to write [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn’t trust a random script from the interwebs that looks like it’s just a proof of concept.

Try `zsh-autocomplete` instead: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete